# Finding the unknown matrix X.

Tags: matrices, random-variables, vectors

I'm practicing for my upcoming exam, and I can't find a way around this part of the question,

Part a)

"Given that A= (2   1  -2   5) , find the inverse of the matrix A+I,
where I is the identity matrix.

Part b)

"Hence, or otherwise, find the matrix X such that AX + A = B, where B= (14 4) --> (it's written as a vector, I am having hard times writing it in that form...)"

Comment: This makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

For part A:

I got the inverse of A+I, which is 1/20 (6     -1
                                           2      3).

For part B:

I got X = (A+I)^-1 = (14 4), but I don't know how to continue. Can I divide it now?